# firefox images flickering during jquery animations

Tags: jquery, image, firefox, animation

My problem is that images starts flickering and flashing in a wired way during fading or sliding animations

in case of fading in/out animations
the problem gets triggered by just scrolling in the page which contains the side bar fading animations.

and in case of sliding the problem just occurs only when the sliding begins.

i dont know if it's how firefox is rendering images or if it's my code which works fine in both chrome and IE ... either way the problem doesn't make any sense.

and by the way i'm on firefox 38 and jquery 1.11.2

Here is my function that i use for fading effects:

```
var listArr = $("#img-list");
var imgIndex = listArr.length - 1;

function fade() {
    var elem = $(listArr[imgIndex]);

    if( elem.css('opacity') == 1 ) {
        elem.fadeTo(2000, 0);
        imgIndex--;
    } else {
        elem.fadeTo(2000, 1);
        imgIndex--;
    }

    if (imgIndex <= 0) {
        imgIndex = listArr.length - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be great if you can give us a link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved

i disabled firefox hardware acceleration ... and now everything works fine.
here is how to disable firefox hardware acceleration:

go to firefox options then to advanced. Uncheck "Use Hardware Acceleration When Available."